# React Component data not being displayed

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to React and trying to write a program where I have created 3 components: Table, Table header and Table Body and included Table header and Table Body into Table.
I am trying to pass the data from App.js using state and trying to display it into the Table component. I am not getting any error, but I am not getting the desired result.

Here is the sreenshot of React dev tools output:

**Here it shows that state has values**:

[image: Here it shows that state has values]

**Here it shows that its empty so data is not being passed I guess**:

[image: Here it shows that its empty so data is not being passed I guess]

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Table from './Table';


class App extends Component {
  /*You can think of state as any data that should be saved and modified 
  without necessarily being added to a database – for example, 
  adding and removing items from a shopping cart before confirming your purchase.*/ 
  state={
    characters:[
      {
        'id':1,
        'name':'Smit',
        'job':'Student'
      },
      {
        'id':2,
        'name':'Tom',
        'job':'Teacher'
      },
      {
        'id':3,
        'name':'Hardee',
        'job':'Friend'
      },
      {
        'id':4,
        'name':'Dom',
        'job':'Principal'
      },
      {
        'id':5,
        'name':'Dik',
        'job':'Cleaner'
      }
    ]
  };

//to remove any data field from table using state
  removeCharacter = index => {
    //console.log(this.state);
    const { characters } = this.state;
    //console.log(characters);
//to update the state if data is modified
    this.setState({
        characters: characters.filter((character, i) => { 
            return i !== index;
        })
    });
}
  render() {
    //declared characters which will contains data to be insterted into table
    const characters=[];
    return (

      <div className="container">
             {/*Need to pass the character into table so passing it through charData variable into Table component */}
            <Table characterData={characters}
                  removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter} 
            />
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Table.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Table extends Component {
    render() {
        const { characterData, removeCharacter } = this.props;

        return (
            <table>
                <TableHeader />
                <TableBody 
                    characterData={characterData} 
                    removeCharacter={removeCharacter} 
                />
            </table>
        );
    }
}
const TableHeader = () => { 
    return (
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    );
}

const TableBody = props => { 
    //passing the props through as a parameter, 
    //and map through the array to return a table row for each object(element) in the array. 
    //This map will be contained in the rows variable, which we’ll return as an expression.
    const rows = props.characterData.map((row, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{row.id}</td>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
                <td>{row.job}</td>
                <td><button onClick={() => props.removeCharacter(index)}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        );
    });

    return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Your characterData prop is being given an empty array. You want to pass this.state.characters to it.

Comment: @Smit Sanghvi, also consider changing the setState method as shown in my answer. It is the recommended approach. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to note here

1) you are setting characters as an empty array inside `render()` before passing it to the TableBody component

Replacing the line with 
`const { characters } = this.state;` or `const characters = this.state.characters`; should solve the issue

2) when using setState to modify the current state, instead of the above method use the functional setState. This is not the issue, but is a better and recommended approach

```
    //console.log(characters);
//to update the state if data is modified
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const { characters } = prevState;
        return { characters: characters.filter((character, i) => { 
            return i !== index;
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re declaring characters as an empty array before passing it to the Table component. Declare characters in your App’s render method the same way you do it in the removeCharacter method.

```
const { characters } = this.state;
```

So

Change

```
   render() {
       //declared characters which will contains data to be insterted into table
       const characters=[];
    return (
```

To

```
    render() {
       //declared characters which will contains data to be insterted into table
       const { characters } = this.state;
     return (
```